# What's good way to display a start up message in an Android app?

Tags: android, user-interface, splash-screen

All,

I'm developing an Android application that connects to other hardware on start up via TCP (over WiFi) .  I'm pretty happy with the software that handles the connection -- it does a good job of establishing the socket connection as well as handling things when the connection is unexpectedly lost.

Unfortunately, my application currently just displays a blank, empty screen until the connection is established, and I expect that this sort of thing may produce unwarranted worry on the part of my users.

I can't figure out how to put up a start-up message informing the user that I have a towel and that there's no need to panic.  Can anybody point me to a method for accomplishing this?  I'll be happy with just about anything that's legible, whether graphical or textual.

Thanks,
R.

Comment: I may have left out an important detail or two... One is that the TCP connection is being set up in an Activity object that loads a SurfaceView rather than a layout defined in an XML file.  All this would probably be much easier if I were loading a layout...

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you choose, you need to get the startup screen displayed and more importantly start responding to UI events before the TCP connection is made - ie, you shouldn't do the TCP connection attempt on the UI thread, as if it takes longer than expected you may get an application not responding error.

Answer (score 1):

Do the networking in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (another thread, so it won't block the UI). Then you can display all kinds of progress indicators in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ProgressDialog`.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html